# Window size and position in inch or points

Tags: python, tkinter

I was able to [figure out](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_dimensions.htm) how to set widget position and dimensions in other units:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x100+400+200")
btn = tk.Button(text="Button")
btn.place(x='20p', y='20p', width='70p', height='20p')
root.mainloop()
```

... and I would like to do the same with the window. However, geometry does not allow for units like `root.geometry("200px100p+400p+200p")`. How can I set the window size using inch or points?

Comment: you can put `Frame` with size in units/points and `root` will resize to expected size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used it before but there is [winfo_fpixels(distance)](https://web.archive.org/web/20190916193344/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_fpixels-method) which converts distance in `p`, `i`, `c` to number of pixels.

---

It shows difference between `points` (`root`) and `pixels` (`other`)

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

x = int(root.winfo_fpixels('200p'))
y = int(root.winfo_fpixels('100p'))
w = int(root.winfo_fpixels('400p'))
h = int(root.winfo_fpixels('200p'))

root.geometry(f"{x}x{y}+{w}+{h}")
root.title('root')

other = tk.Toplevel()
other.geometry(f"200x100+400+200")
other.title('other')

root.mainloop()
```